# Extracting text with XPath in Python

Tags: parsing, xpath, lxml

I have a page. It's `html` structure is like this:

```
<p>
    <strong style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;">
        <span>
            Text
        </span>
    </strong>
    <span>
        Text
    </span>
    <span>
        Text
        <em>
            Text
        </em>
        Text
    </span>
    <span>
        Text
        <strong>
            Text
        </strong>
    </span>
</p>
```

And I want to extract text from each `p` tag. They must be separated with new lines.

```
first p tag:   TextTextText
next p tag:    TextTextText
```

What I have done.

```
url="http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id="+str(i)+"&Itemid="+str(i+1)
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
pageWritten = page.read()
pageReady = pageWritten.decode('utf-8')
xmldata = lxml.html.document_fromstring(pageReady)
for element in xmldata.xpath('//p[@class="MsoNormal"]'):
    joined_text=u''.join(element.xpath('descendant::text()'))
print joined_text
```

But it prints out only the last `p` and I don't understand why. Guys, I'll very glad for any help.

Comment: The HTML snippet you posted does not contain this "MsoNormal" class you are selecting, so we can't check your XPath expression without the original content you are analyzing. I cannot access this website (times out all the time, only Google cache has some content). Could you post a sample HTML page somewhere (on some pastebin) or a snippet of it in your question? Also you may try out `descendant-or-self::text()` or `//text()` instead, or even use `lxml.html.tostring(element, method="text", encoding=unicode)` to export the `element` as a string representation

Comment: Thanx for replying. Here is a small piece (p tag): http://pastebin.com/gKJyL14r

Comment: Dear @paul t. I used lxml.html.tostring(element, method="text", encoding=unicode) and it works as I want. Thanx a lot.